# Corollary of Theorem 2.12 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

In Rudin´s Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Theorem 2.12 shows that if $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of countable sets, then

$$ S=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \quad \text{is countable} $$

Theorem 2.12 is followed by a corollary stating that $T=\cup_{\alpha\in A}B_\alpha$, where $A$ is at most countable (finite or countable) and $B_\alpha$ is at most countable for each $\alpha\in A$, is at most countable because $T$ is equivalent to a subset of S, which is countable.

It is of course a very intuitive idea that $T$ and a subset of S can be put in $1$-$1$ correspondence, but I'm having trouble defining a bijection between them.

Can somebody give an example of a bijective function from $T$ to a subset of $S$ ?

THANKS and i hope my question isn't too dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T$ be given as you've described it. If $A$ is finite, let $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k\}$ be an enumeration of $A$.  Then define
$$
E_{n} = \begin{cases}
B_{\alpha_n} & B_{\alpha_n} \text{ is countable}\\
B_{\alpha_n} \cup \Bbb Z & B_{\alpha_n} \text{ is finite}\\
\Bbb Z & n > k
\end{cases}
$$
If $A$ is infinite, let $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\}$ be an enumeration, and get rid of the third case in the definition above.

Since $B_{\alpha_n} \subseteq E_n$ for all $n$, we must have $T \subseteq S$. $S$ is countable, since it fits the description in theorem 2.12.

Comment: Why separate the cases? There is no harm in always taking the union with $\Bbb Z$, or some other fixed countable set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The idea from my end was to make the thought process clearer and emphasize that the union with $\Bbb Z$ is a "fix" for the finite sets. But I agree, there's no harm in some redundant unions.